# ajax success event doesn't work after being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

After searching here on SO and google, didn't find an answer to my problem.

The animation doesn't seem to trigger, tried a simple alert, didn't work either.

The function works as it is supposed (almost) as it does what i need to, excluding the success part.

Why isn't the success event being called?

```
$(function() {
    $(".seguinte").click(function() {
        var fnome = $('.fnome').val();
        var fmorada = $('.fmorada').val();
        var flocalidade = $('.flocalidade').val();
        var fcodigopostal = $('.fcodigopostal').val();
        var ftelemovel = $('.ftelemovel').val();
        var femail = $('.femail').val();
        var fnif = $('.fnif').val();
        var fempresa = $('.fempresa').val();

        var dataString = 'fnome='+ fnome + '&fmorada=' + fmorada + '&flocalidade=' + flocalidade + '&fcodigopostal=' + fcodigopostal + '&ftelemovel=' + ftelemovel  + '&femail=' + femail + '&fnif=' + fnif + '&fempresa=' + fempresa;


        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/ajaxload/editclient.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function() {
                    $('.primeirosector').animate({ "left": "+=768px" }, "fast" );
            }
        });
        return false;
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Check your console on the Network tab, is the request being sent ok?

Comment: @tymeJV Yes, the request is being sent with no problems.

Comment: Did you try adding an error handler to the ajax call ?

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to pass query string in data it should be json data.
Does your method edit client has all the parameters you are passing?
A simple way to test this is doing the following:

change this line to be like this

```
url: "/ajaxload/editclient.php" + "?" + dataString;
```

and remove this line

```
data: dataString
```

The correct way of doing it should be, create a javascript object and send it in the data like so:

```
var sendData ={
        fnome: $('.fnome').val(),
        fmorada: $('.fmorada').val(),
        flocalidade: $('.flocalidade').val(),
        fcodigopostal: $('.fcodigopostal').val(),
        ftelemovel: $('.ftelemovel').val(),
        femail: $('.femail').val(),
        fnif: $('.fnif').val(),
        fempresa: $('.fempresa').val()
}

$.ajax({
  url: "/ajaxload/editclient.php",
  dataType: 'json',
  data: sendData,
  success: function() {
                    $('.primeirosector').animate({ "left": "+=768px" }, "fast" );
            }
});
```

Another thing shouldn't this be a post request?
Hope it helps